# Random number generator for my discord bot in discord.js

Tags: javascript, random, discord, discord.js

```js
else if (parts[0] === Prefix + 'number') {
        message.channel.send(message.author.username + ' What is the minimum number');
        if (parts[0] === Math.int) {
            var MinNum = (Discord.Message);
            console.log("minimum number is " + MinNum);
            message.channel.send(message.author.username + ' what is the maximum number');
        } if (parts[0] === Math.int) {
            var MaxNum = (Discord.Message);
            console.log("Maximum number is " + MaxNum);

            const RandomNum = Random.int(MinNum, MaxNum);
            message.channel.send(Message.author.username + " number is " + RandomNum);
        } else if (parts[0] === Math.int == false) {
            message.channel.send("Sorry " + message.author.username + " that is an invalid number");
        }
    }
```

So this is some code for a random number generator, when someone says `-number`, my bot asks the user what is the minimun number, when the user puts a number that number is set to the `MinNum` variable, and the minimun number is logged in my console. After this, it asks the user what is the maximum number, next it is suppose to do the same thing but with the maximum number, after the user inputs the maximum number the random number generator spits out a random number between those two values, and if the user does not put a number my bot says sorry (username) that is an invalid number.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `Math.int` is, and why you think that `if (parts[0] === Prefix + 'number')` it will also be `(parts[0] === Math.int)`. Unfortunately, it won't work like this. You can't accept a command and accept any follow-up messages as a response to your bot's question.

However, this is a nice use case for message collectors. First, you can send the first question and ask for the first limit. Once this message is sent, you can set up a message collector in the channel using [`channel.createMessageCollector`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=createMessageCollector).

It accepts a `filter` and an `options` object. With the filter you can check if the incoming message is from the author who typed the command and if their response is a valid number.

`createMessageCollector` returns a [`MessageCollector`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageCollector), so you can subscribe to the [`collect`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageCollector?scrollTo=e-collect) and [`end`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageCollector?scrollTo=e-end) events.

The `collect` event is emitted whenever a message is collected. If this is the first response, you can store it in an array (`limits`) and send a new message asking for the maximum.

Once the user sends a second valid number, the `end` event fires, so you can generate a random number and send it to the user. The `end` event also fires when the max time is reached, so you can check if the reason is the timeout and if it is, send an error message.

You could also create a helper function to generate a random integer between two numbers:

```js
function randomInt([min, max]) {
  if (min > max) {
    [min, max] = [max, min];
  }
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
```

And here is the full code:

```js
if (command === 'number') {
  const embedMin = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(` Get a random number `)
    .setColor('GREEN')
    .setDescription('What is the minimum number?');

  await message.channel.send(embedMin);
  // filter checks if the response is from the author who typed the command
  // and if the response is a valid number
  const filter = (response) =>
    response.author.id === message.author.id && !isNaN(response.content.trim());

  const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, {
    // set up the max wait time the collector runs
    time: 60000, // ms
    // set up the max responses to collect
    max: 2,
  });

  // it stores the user responses
  const limits = [];

  collector.on('collect', async (response) => {
    const num = parseInt(response.content.trim(), 10);
    limits.push(num);

    // if this is the first number sent
    if (limits.length === 1) {
      const embedMax = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(` Get a random number `)
        .setColor('GREEN')
        .addField('Minimum', limits[0])
        .setDescription('What is the maximum number?');

      // send the next question
      message.channel.send(embedMax);
    }
  });

  // runs when either the max limit is reached or the max time
  collector.on('end', (collected, reason) => {
    console.log({ collected });
    if (reason === 'time') {
      const embedTimeout = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(` Get a random number `)
        .setColor('RED')
        .setDescription(
          `I'm sorry, I haven't received a response in a minute, so I'm off now. If you need a new random number again, type \`${prefix}number\``,
        );
      message.channel.send(embedTimeout);
    }

    if (limits.length === 2) {
      // get a random number
      const embedRandom = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(` Get a random number `)
        .setColor('GREEN')
        .addField('Minimum', limits[0], true)
        .addField('Maximum', limits[1], true)
        .setDescription(`Your random number is: ${randomInt(limits)}`);

      message.channel.send(embedRandom);
    }
  });
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks but im getting an error message:  await message.channel.send(embedMin);

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: You need to add the `async` keyword before the function you add this code to.

Comment: can you update the code so I can see how you added the async because ive never used async

Comment: In your other question you had `bot.on('message', (message) => { ...`, you need to change that to `bot.on('message', async (message) => { ...`. I hope it helps.

Comment: that helped but and i saw that you used MessageEmbed instead of Discord.MessageEmbed so I fixed that, but now in getting a huge error saying that I don't have a module installed what module do i have to install

Comment: The only dependency is discord.js, what was the error message?

Comment: well the error message is gone, but now when I do -number, nothing happens, but when i say anything after i say -number the bot just spams embeds, it spams 5 embeds, stops for a bit, then spams 5 more, and repeat

Comment: Can you send me your full code? You could even paste it on a site like https://pastebin.com/ and send the link here so I can take a look.

Comment: That's not the whole code. Anyway, you don't need to add ` bot.on('message', async (message) => {` there. There should be one already before those if statements like `if (parts[0] === Prefix + 'number')`.

Comment: this is all way to confusing imma just get rid of the -number code

Comment: Not sure what's confusing.