# Discord.js bot - embedded content doesn't appear on sending a command separately, but displays all the embeds when needed commands are typed together

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Here's an image explaining the error:-

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRyPL.png)

So, **s.gw** is the command which triggers the first embed. After this embed, typing an **ok** message would then lead to the display of a new embed. Not typing an **ok** or **end** message would lead to the display of the "invalid input" message.

But, because of this bug, entering **s.gw** AND **ok** together will only result in the display of the second embed. I also added a few more embeds which the user would trigger using certain keywords, but they all only get triggered when all of the command messages are entered at once.

Any sort of help would do. I'm new to JavaScript and Discord bot dev in general.

Here's the code for the "game":-

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const animalArray = ["lion", "mongoose", "chimpanzee"];
const foodArray = ["bread", "applie pie", "cake"];

exports.run=async(bot, message, args)=>{

    const embedTemp = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
    const beginEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
    const embedEnd = new Discord.MessageEmbed();

    const aniEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
    const fooEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();

    const animal = animalArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*animalArray.length)];
    const food = foodArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*foodArray.length)];

    


    embedTemp.setColor("#EC5CA6");
    embedTemp.setTitle("Welcome to Guess-The-Word!");
    embedTemp.setDescription("Guess the word generated by the computer! \nYou only get 3 tries! \nGood Luck! \n\nReply with **ok** to start or **end** to stop.");
    message.channel.send(embedTemp);

    let ok = ' ok ';
    let end = ' end ';

    // let play = false;

    if(message.content.includes(ok))
    {
        beginEmbed.setColor("#EC5CA6");
        beginEmbed.setTitle("Choose a topic: (reply with no. given alongside topic)");
        beginEmbed.setDescription("**1.**  Animals \n\n**2.**  Food");
        message.channel.send(beginEmbed);

        if(message.content.includes('1'))
        {
            aniEmbed.setColor("#EC5CA6");
            aniEmbed.setTitle("Guess the animal:");
            message.channel.send(aniEmbed);
        }
        else if(message.content.includes('2'))
        {
            fooEmbed.setColor("#EC5CA6");
            fooEmbed.setTitle("Guess the food item:");
            message.channel.send(fooEmbed);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(message.content.includes(end))
        {
            embedEnd.setColor("#EC5CA6");  
            embedEnd.setTitle("Thanks for playing :)");
            embedEnd.setDescription("The game has ended.");          
            message.channel.send(embedEnd);
        }
        else
        {
            message.channel.send("invalid input");
        }
    }

}
exports.help={
    name: 'gw'
}
```

Still have a lot to do, but getting this out of the way seemed like the better idea.

Comment: You're checking the `message.content` of the command. You should look into collectors. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67760949/6126373 Or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66968680/6126373

Comment: thank you, I'll try to implement that into my code.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is just fetching the content of the message that contains the command, meaning it will not register any other response outside of the command input. You are checking for "message.content", and message.content will only be registered for the command, for example:

User1 types the command "/say Test" and you have "console.log(message.content)" written for the /say command, the bot will log "say test" and not any message sent after the command.

As stated in the comments, what you need is a message collector, so the bot will listen to responses for x amount of time after the command has been sent.

You must make sure that the message collector fetches for lower cased responses, this way if a user inputs a letter in capital, it won't affect the response.